# Etiquette or rules on criteria for new arXiv submissions on expanded work

Tags: arxiv

In computer science, I'm mindful of arXiv's policy against multiple submissions for the same paper, favoring updates via revisions for corrections or minor changes.

My case is a bit special regarding an expansion of my work: a year ago, I posted a 14-page paper on arXiv about a technique for a specific problem in my subfield, titled "Improving bla bla in Problem name." Since then, I've broadened the application of this technique to 12 additional problems, leading to a major rewrite and expansion of the paper to 61 pages, now with a focus on the technique's wider applicability and retitled "Using Technique A to solve bla bla-type Problems."

This leaves me with options: revise the original submission on arXiv, withdraw the paper and resubmit, or treat it as a new, distinct submission. What's the correct approach according to arXiv's etiquette/rules? Ideally, I want the paper to reach the feed of researchers in my community, and I'm not sure if simply revising the paper would do that.

Comment: Why not formal publication instead of a preprint?

Comment: @Buffy I'm submitting the paper for publications, but it takes some time, and I'd like to just share my results (as is common in my subfield) since many people are working on these problems and doing minor improvements too.

Comment: @Buffy, of course, unless the true issue is getting some credit for passing some gate-keeping, the actual work will become truly published vastly faster on arXiv rather than via "journals"...

Comment: IMHO, such a major expansion of a paper should be a new preprint. But I do not think there are some clear cut rules about this.

Comment: Is the original preprint submitted for publication? Has it been cited by other authors already in preprint form? Please add this information to the question; it might be useful to give you the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in computer science, but what I tend to see in cases where the new document is **substantially** different from the previous one (which yours clearly is) is indeed a new preprint. This is especially recommended if people have relied upon and cited the earlier version. It is common and helpful to use the comment field to describe the relation to the older document, for example that is an expanded version, that it supersedes the prior version, etc. Withdrawing the prior preprint should only be done for [appropriate reasons](https://info.arxiv.org/help/withdraw.html), and arXiv is clear on that wanting to post a new version does not qualify, so you certainly shouldn't do that.